# Arabic validation

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, валидация

Нужно сделать проверку поля на наличие "только" арабских символов. Нашел подсказку использовать регулярное выражение и что-то вроде следующего: **[\u0600-\u06ff\u0750-\u077f\ufb50-\ufc3f\ufe70-\ufefca-zA-Z- .ـ]** Но у меня возникла проблема, первый символ справа не попадает в диапазон, а если его удалить, то следующий от него выпадает из диапазона (хотя до удаления он проходил).

Comment: Предлагаю вставить любую букву, что бы её не показывало, а остальные...

Answer (score 1):

Для арабского исплльзуйте [\u0600-\u06FF]

[тут еще примеры для других языков](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block)

Comment: Проблема в том, что я уже пробовал такой способ и у меня первый символ не попадает в диапазон, а все остальное - попадает. Но если его удалить, то следующий от него - выпадает. Я не могу понять, с чем связанно данное поведение.

Comment: Вероятно с символом направления письма.

Comment: `\u200e` если что этот символ.

Comment: можете привести пример строки?

Comment: Да, конечно. Вот пример строки: مرحبا كيف حالك
С арабским у меня никак, по-этому я не могу понять что я делаю не так )

Comment: /[\u0600-\u06FF]/.test('مرحبا كيف حالك')
возвращает true

Comment: Сделайте `escape( input.value )` и приведите результат.